# How can I loop in an multi-dimensional array to get the capture the the last node using spread operator

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, data-structures

Consider this example. I am trying to move to first element of 2-D ARRAY which contains two array items and use spread operator until I get **text** inside the inner most array.

```
     let arr = [
   [ {
      type: 'paragraph',
      children: [{ text: 'First line.' }],
    },
  
  {
      type: 'paragraph',
      children: [{ text: 'Second.' }],
    }
  
  ],[
    {
      type: 'paragraph',
      children: [{ text: 'Third.' }],
    },
  
  {
      type: 'paragraph',
      children: [{ text: 'Fourth.' }],
    }
  
  ]
  ]

  //const newArr = [...arr[0]]  // more logic
  //result to ['first line','Second.']
```

[JS Fiddle to test the array](https://jsfiddle.net/hussamkhatib/e9602gq8/10/)

Comment: What is your expected output. Would you like to spread all children together?

Comment: yes i want spread all the children from arr[0] , later i will extract only the text from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think the spread operator will be of any help here, but consider this:

```js
let arr = [
 [ {
    type: 'paragraph',
    children: [{ text: 'First line.' }],
  },

{
    type: 'paragraph',
    children: [{ text: 'Second.' }],
  }

],[
  {
    type: 'paragraph',
    children: [{ text: 'Third.' }],
  },

{
    type: 'paragraph',
    children: [{ text: 'Fourth.' }],
  }

]
]
let result1 = [];
arr.flat().forEach(element => result1.push(element.children[0].text));
console.log("Result1:", result1);

// or just group the children from arr[0] together:
let result2 = [];
arr[0].forEach(element => result2.push(element.children[0]));
console.log("Result2:", result2);
```